# Missing MongoDB\Driver files (PHP)

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm having a ton of trouble trying to find these files. I've downloaded and included everything I can find:

- extension=php_mongodb.dll in php.ini
- ran `composer require mongodb/mongodb` in project directory
- pecl install mongodb doesn't work (the error tells me the package doesn't exist)
- looked through source code of both the extension and php adapter https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver

Here's an image of (some) of the missing files and a bit of my file structure.
I don't wanna get in trouble so I'm missing:

[image]

```
use MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException as DriverInvalidArgumentException;
use MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException as DriverRuntimeException;
use MongoDB\Driver\Manager;
use MongoDB\Driver\ReadConcern;
use MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference;
use MongoDB\Driver\Session;
use MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern;
```

Comment: Seems to be a PhpStorm (if I recognize your editor correctly) detection issue?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your editor?

Comment: I've restarted the editor and my PC many, many times.